# Combine multiple JSON files into one; retrieve using jQuery/getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have some jQuery code which retrieves content using getJSON().
There are *n* JSON files, which are retrieved from the server as needed:

> /json-content/data0.json
>
> /json-content/data1.json
>
> /json-content/data2.json
>
> etc...

Instead, I want to store all the JSON in a single file to **reduce the number of HTTP requests** needed to retrieve the data.

What is the best way to combine the JSON files into one?
If I concatenate the JSON files together, it no longer works with getJSON().

*UPDATE - clarified my question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to reduce the number of HTTP requests from the client, one possible way is like this:

1. Build a server side proxy that get JSon files from the third party data sources
2. Merge your 3 JSon files in one single JSon file
3. Make a single $.getJSON() call to your single JSon from client

To merge Json files, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198962/merge-two-json-objects-programmatically) post.

Comment: How do I 'blend' these JSON files?

Answer (score 4):

Either as individual attributes or as an array

```
{
 "data1":{stuff for data1},
 "data2":{stuff for data2},
 "data3":{stuff for data3}
}
```

or

```
{"response":[
  {stuff for data1},
  {stuff for data2},
  {stuff for data3}]}
```